# android layout is not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout

I know its probably something simple I am missing here, but for some reason I can't seem to get my layout to display when I run my app using the emulator.   Any feedback would be great.  Thanks

my fragment

```
package com.pctoolman.planme.app;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class PlanMeMainFragment extends Fragment {

private Button mNewButton, mExistingButton;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planme_main_fragment, container, false);

    mNewButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);
    mNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewEventSetupActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    return  v;
}




}
```

my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ff3a0b">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/plan_me"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#2c58ff"
        android:id="@+id/textView">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_event_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/new_event"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/existing_event"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/existing_event"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the activity file

```
package com.pctoolman.planme.app;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PlanMeMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.planme_main_activity);
}



}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Where is your activity?

Comment: Did you really leave the RelativeLayout open?

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause nothing to be displayed. Are you sure the Fragment is being added to the activity properly?

Comment: I added the activity file.  Also the RelativeLayout closing statement is all the way on the bottom of xml file.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a transatcion via `FragmentManager` to show your fragment in the activity. Suppose you have container (FrameLayout, for example) with `id = fragment_container` in your `planme_main_activity.xml`. If so, you should add the following after `setContentView(R.layout.planme_main_activity);`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PlanMeMainFragment())
    .commit();
```

But if you declared fragment directly in XML, please post your `planme_main_activity.xml`

Comment: Thanks your last sentence is where my issue was.  I was calling the activity xml instead of the fragment xml.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you haven't positioned the buttons properly. It's easy to move things around in a relative layout. You don't need to use gravity. You can use:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
```

I'm assuming you cut out the closing tag for the RL.

Comment: I removed the gravity. I have the RL closing tag is on the very bottom. When I run the app all I get is a blank white screen.  Thanks.